# Why location in Google maps shown on my pc is different than the one shown on my mobile phone?

Tags: android, google-maps

If I am not wrong, the only way Google can know my location is through my cellphone. This means that if my cellphone is showing the correct location for me, there seems to be no reason for computer to show the different location. (Synchronization across devices, refreshing etc has been done several times) However, what I see is strange to me. My location on mobile phone is different (and inaccurate) than my location on the desktop computer. The locations show the same area of city but they are separated by around 100-200 meters. My question is, if the Google map is anyway fetching my location using my cellphone, why is it showing incorrect location on my pc? Thanks in advance.

Comment: there are two ways to know location, GPS provider and network provider. GPS provides you exact location but network Location is not most accurate. so this could be reason.

Comment: But I think that location was not being shown at all in Google maps sometime back. So my best guess is that it is indeed fetched from mobile phone.

Answer (score 0):

Most smartphones are equipped with a gps devices.

This allow accuracy unlike PC which most don't have a gps device.

Google Maps website uses permissions to your location and most likely other web browser location information, but they will never get as accurate as devices.

Comment: How does this answer my question?

Comment: I am pretty sure that my computer is not being used to see the location. I am logged onto few more computers away from this one and they are not being shown in the map.

Comment: when you press, current location and give it permissions, it will get your location

Comment: @media : This question remains unanswered. I think everyone misunderstood the question. The question says that though the mobile device should show a better accuracy, in fact the desktop computer does so.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue since construction started near my house. Google maps on mobile devices inaccurately shows the highway in front of my street as closed. We are currently using Eastbound lanes for east and west traffic flow so the road isn't closed, just detoured. So it routes everyone to turn down a parallel street that dead ends. There's no way to get to my house that way. My street is one way in one way out. However using Google maps on my laptop shows perfect directions. I've tried to update this being a contributor on the app but nothing has been corrected even though they say they've received my update. Using my laptop there's nothing to fix because it's correct there.

Answer (score -1):

I've found the opposite to be true.  I have a more accurate location reading using google maps through my PC than on my smart phone.  The location, time last online etc . . is more accurate on PC.